# Proxmox recover data from formatted vm disk

Tags: windows, proxmox

We had a Windows VM in our proxmox server with one accounting program and suddenly, it crashed at night.

When we connected to check what's wrong and we noticed a blue screen with the Windows error 0xc0000225 so we tried a few things but never formatted the drive. I tried to do a list partition but they are missing.

Is there any way to recover data from the vm disk image?
I tried recovering windows but now is missing.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a copy of the disk. Use `dd` for that.

```
dd if=/var/lib/libvirt/images/guest1.img of=/var/lib/libvirt/images/guest1_copy.img
```

After you made a copy, try to mount the disk on the proxmox host. Before the actual mounting, one needs information about the partition layout. Use `kpartx` to display the partition table. (Note, that kpartx may need to get installed before.)

```
kpartx -l /var/lib/libvirt/images/guest1_copy.img
```

and then map the partitions

```
kpartx -a /var/lib/libvirt/images/guest1_copy.img
```

After that, check if the mapping worked.

```
ls /dev/mapper/loop*
```

Every partition should be available as loop device. If that worked, the disk can be mounted - fs driver presence assumed - with the normal mount command. For example

```
mount /dev/mapper/loop0p2 /mnt -o loop,ro
```

if the desired partition is partition 2.

See [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/virtualization/sect-virtualization-troubleshooting_xen-accessing_data_on_guest_disk_image) for more information.